# Apache Flink EventTime processing not working

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am trying to perform stream-stream join using Flink v1.11 app on KDA. Join wrt to `ProcessingTime` works, but with `EventTime` I don’t see any output records from Flink.

Here is my code with EventTime processing which is not working,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    DataStream<Trade> input1 = createSourceFromInputStreamName1(env)
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                    WatermarkStrategy.<Trade>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                            .withTimestampAssigner(((event, l) -> event.getEventTime()))
            );
    DataStream<Company> input2 = createSourceFromInputStreamName2(env)
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                    WatermarkStrategy.<Company>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                            .withTimestampAssigner(((event, l) -> event.getEventTime()))
            );
    DataStream<String> joinedStream = input1.join(input2)
            .where(new TradeKeySelector())
            .equalTo(new CompanyKeySelector())
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<Trade, Company, String>() {
                @Override
                public String join(Trade t, Company c) {
                    return t.getEventTime() + ", " + t.getTicker() + ", " + c.getName() + ", " + t.getPrice();
                }
            });
    joinedStream.addSink(createS3SinkFromStaticConfig());
    env.execute("Flink S3 Streaming Sink Job");
}
```

I got a similar join working with ProcessingTime

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
    DataStream<Trade> input1 = createSourceFromInputStreamName1(env);
    DataStream<Company> input2 = createSourceFromInputStreamName2(env);
    DataStream<String> joinedStream = input1.join(input2)
            .where(new TradeKeySelector())
            .equalTo(new CompanyKeySelector())
            .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(10000)))
            .apply (new JoinFunction<Trade, Company, String> (){
                @Override
                public String join(Trade t, Company c) {
                    return t.getEventTime() + ", " + t.getTicker() + ", " + c.getName() + ", " + t.getPrice();
                }
            });
    joinedStream.addSink(createS3SinkFromStaticConfig());
    env.execute("Flink S3 Streaming Sink Job");
}
```

Sample records from two streams which I am trying to join:

```
{'eventTime': 1611773705, 'ticker': 'TBV', 'price': 71.5}
{'eventTime': 1611773705, 'ticker': 'TBV', 'name': 'The Bavaria'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong, but any of the following could cause this job to not produce any output:

- A problem with watermarking. For example, if one of the streams becomes idle, then the watermarks will cease to advance. Or if there are no events after a window, then the watermark will not advance far enough to close that window. Or if the timestamps aren't actually in ascending order (with the `forMonotonousTimestamps` strategy, the events should be in order by timestamp), the pipeline could be silently dropping all of the out-of-order events.
- The StreamingFileSink only finalizes its output during checkpointing, and does not finalize whatever files are pending if and when the job is stopped.
- A windowed join behaves like an inner join, and requires at least one event from each input stream in order to produce any results for a given window interval. From the example you shared, it looks like this is not the issue.

---

Update:

Given that what you (appear to) want to do is to join each Trade with the latest Company record available at the time of the Trade, a lookup join or a temporal table join seem like they might be good approaches.

Here are a couple of examples:

https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/master/joins/04/04_lookup_joins.md

https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/master/joins/03/03_kafka_join.md

Some documentation:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#event-time-temporal-join

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/versioned_tables.html

Comment: I don't fully understand what the second issue you mentioned could be. Since the ProcessingTime join works, I am hoping to eliminate the third issue as well.

I think this might be a watermark issue, which I am still getting my feet wet with.
As soon as I start the Flink app, the <task>.currentInputWatermark is -9223372036854776000 (about Long.MIN_VALUE). 

As I start ingesting events into the stream, it moves to 1611929908 (about 3 hours ago), while my records have a timestamp of 1611939889 (about now). 

I am using the forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(10)) strategy.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is most likely a watermarking problem. Since the code you shared shows `forMonotonousTimestamps` rather than `forBoundedOutOfOrderness`, I'm not sure I have an accurate idea of what your job is doing with watermarks.

Comment: I changed back to the exact code in the description, and now I see the output from the join!!!
I see the <task>.currentInputWatermark close to the event time as well. I am confident that the same configuration did not work before. I no longer know what I am doing :)

Comment: There's a tutorial on watermarks at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/streaming_analytics.html#event-time-and-watermarks that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a use case where the Company stream in the above example is a low volume stream. Let's assume the company name changes every hour. And the Trade stream is a high volume stream with a trade every second. I want to join all the trades with the company. Since the window size is common for both streams, I don't want to hold the Trade stream state for an hour before performing the join, for example, in a tumbling window.

Comment: Will Interval Join be a good candidate here, where for each trade I can look up in the past hour for the company event? In case there are two company events within the window, is there a way I can just pick the latest event for the join? I am thinking if versioned tables will solve this.